# Delphi 10 - Executing command line on Android and get the output live

Tags: android, delphi

I am trying to execute a command line with Delphi 10 on Android and get the output of the command.

I'm using files from here:

https://github.com/FMXExpress/android-object-pascal-wrapper/tree/master/android-23

Here is my code:

```
uses Classes,
     Androidapi.Helpers,
     java.lang.Process, java.lang.Runtime,
     java.io.OutputStream, java.io.InputStream,
     java.io.InputStreamReader, java.io.BufferedReader;

procedure Execute(sCmd: string; sOut : TStringList);
var Process : JProcess;
    Runtime : JRuntime;
    Input   : JInputStream;
    BuffInput : JBufferedReader;  
begin

    Process := TJRuntime.JavaClass.getRuntime.exec(StringToJString(sCmd));
    //Input := JInputStream(Process.getInputStream);
    BuffInput := JBufferedReader(jInputStreamReader(Process.getInputStream) );
while (s  = '') do
begin
    s := JStringToString(BuffInput.readLine);
    sOut.Add(s);
 end;

 //--- Compile but get Segmentation fault(11) at 
 // s := JStringToString(BuffInput.readLine);

end;
```

Comment: Did you read the Android documentation for the [`InputStream`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html) and [`OutputStream`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStream.html) classes yet?

Comment: In what way are you stuck?

Comment: -Remy , yes i read it but i dont get any result so far, sorry im a noob for all android stuff.

Comment: You *dont get any result so far* because you've made no effort to *get any result*. What have you tried to get any input or output from the streams?

Comment: If you call 1 day of trying a no effort ... 
anyways i found a lot of sample to do it in java, but like i said im noob for convert java to delphi


BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
     InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

String s = null;
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the *nice comment* of Ken White, i digg more on the problem.

1: i need to use Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes and not java.io.InputStream -> Input.available is always 0 if i use from java.io.InputStream

2: After executing my command, i need to do Process.waitFor. i guest i can't have a live output like good old dos

3: if someone know a better way to do this, your welcome :P

```
procedure Execute(sCmd: string; sOut : TStringList);
var Process : JProcess;
    Runtime : JRuntime;

    Input   : JInputStream;

    x, bufflen: Integer;

    s: string;
    buff : TJavaArray<Byte>;

begin
  Process := TJRuntime.JavaClass.getRuntime.exec(StringToJString(sCmd));
  Process.waitFor;

  Input := Process.getInputStream;
  bufflen := Input.available;

  buff := TJavaArray<Byte>.Create(bufflen);
  Input.read(buff);

  s := '';

  for x := 0 to bufflen - 1 do
    s := s + chr(buff[x]);

  sOut.Add(s); 

end;
```